# how to create an Ajax menu in the _layout.cshtml view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i would like to have a menu in my _layout.cshtml view that will partially render the body.
Like an ajax menu with master page in the old days and rendering only the content place holder.

i have this piece of code in the view :

```
<div id="body">

             <aside class="Menu_aside">
            <ul class="Menu_ul">
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink( "Current Settings", "Index", "CurrentSettings", new AjaxOptions {  InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace ,LoadingElementId = "_body"} )</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Call History", "Index", "CallHistory" )</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <div id ="_body">
       @RenderSection( "featured", required: false )

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
            </div>
    </div>
```

but this only adds some strange behavior over my view.

i would like that when pressing the link only the "content" part will rendered.
i'm sure it is possible i just haven't figure out how.
Thanks

Comment: have you checked on partial views

Comment: can you please share more thoughts ?

Comment: No idea ? anyone ? when i'm using partial views i'm loosing the page view - i need to update only the the content page and the rest i want  it to be static.

Comment: are you talking about having a masterlayout

Comment: yes. i would like to have a menu in the _layout.cshtml file that will only update the other views section

Comment: i know how to do it in a single view when there is an action but failing to understand how to do it in the main _layout.cshtml

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Ajax to update RenderBody() section with VS 2012 Internet Template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425178/how-to-use-ajax-to-update-renderbody-section-with-vs-2012-internet-template)

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question here. [How to use Ajax to update RenderBody() section with VS 2012 Internet Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425178/how-to-use-ajax-to-update-renderbody-section-with-vs-2012-internet-template) Its answer should be what you're looking for.